# JSON object to String Array

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, response

This is the response I am getting using retrofit in android.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "name": "Test3",
    "password": "123456",
    "phoneNumber": "0000000000"
  },
  {
    Soon....
  }
]
```

How do I make an Array out of it? I am trying the code below but nothing seems to happen.

```
            //getting the whole json object from the response
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            ArrayList<retrofitUser> modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<retrofitfitUser>();
            JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray(""); //what should i put in ""


        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                retrofitUser modelRecycler = new retrofitUser();
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                modelRecycler.setEmail(dataobj.getString("email"));
                modelRecycler.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                modelRecycler.setPhoneNumber(dataobj.getString("phoneNumber"));
                modelRecycler.setPassword(dataobj.getString("password"));

                modelRecyclerArrayList.add(modelRecycler);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[{"id":1,"email":"test2@gmail.com","name":"Test3","password":"123456","phoneNumber":"0000000000"}]
```

**Don't**

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("");
```

You should try with

```
   try
  {

        JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) 
        {   

                retrofitUser modelRecycler = new retrofitUser();
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                modelRecycler.setEmail(dataobj.getString("email"));
                modelRecycler.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                modelRecycler.setPhoneNumber(dataobj.getString("phoneNumber"));
                modelRecycler.setPassword(dataobj.getString("password"));

                modelRecyclerArrayList.add(modelRecycler);

         }
  }
  catch (JSONException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
```